# Does StoreKit and SKDownload guarantee integrity of finished download?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

My app downloads non-consumable IAP content with StoreKit, hosted by Apple. Do I have to check the integrity of the finished download (e.g. calculate a SHA1 or MD5) or can I trust the integrity of the download when the delegate gets a "download finished" call?